# Skip deleted/empty rows sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, for-loop, achartengine

I am populating AChartEngine from sqlite database and I need all of the data to be displayed.   The problem I'm having is when I delete a record the graph series stops populating at the deleted record.    I need to find a way to skip over deleted/empty records and continue populating my graph.    I need it to do it the same way listview skips over deleted records and keeps on displaying all rows.    I am very new to a lot of this and am having a very difficult time with this.     I have tried to write if statements in order to skip deleted/empty rows but nothing seems to work.    Thank you for helping!

in my graphing activity:

```
    for (int i = 1; !c.isAfterLast(); i++)  {

         String value1 = db.getValue1(i);
         String value2 = db.getValue2(i);

         c.moveToNext();

         double x7 = Double.parseDouble(value1);
         double y7 = Double.parseDouble(value2);

         myseries.add(x7, y7);  

         }
```

I am getting error:  `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

If I surround with try and catch it will populate rows up until the deleted record.

"EDIT"
in my sqlite database:

```
  public String getValue1(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ EMP_DEPT };
    Cursor c = db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String value1 = c.getString(0);


        return value1;


    }
    return null;
    }






public String getValue2(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ EMP_DATE1 };
    Cursor c = db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
    c.moveToFirst();
    String value2 = c.getString(0);


        return value2;


    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: this really suggests that something is fundamentally wrong with your set-up if deleting anything in your database can affect your graph like this. essentially, you *should* be loading your graph series from a query to the database and this graph series has the sole responsibility for providing data to your graph. affecting the database after it has been made shouldn't affect the graph series and thus the graph.

Comment: The graph itself is not the problem...    The problem i'm having is in the query and how i'm populating the series.   What I assume I need is a statement in my query to skip empty rows.     Look at updated post, I have included my query.

Comment: my point is that the population step and deleting step should be distinct steps such that one can never conflict with the other, if things are being done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your safety net for commands on rows that don't exist is to use `if (c != null){` and then perform your commands inside that block, *but* a `Cursor` request from a query will never come up `null`, it will instead result in a cursor object with no rows.

A more appropriate solution to use this as your safety net instead `if (c.moveToFirst()){` Because the method itself returns a `boolean` for if the method actually carried itself out in the first place - `true` if it moved and `false` if not (which occurs when there's no rows to move into). another check, if you wish, would be to see how many rows the cursor has with `c.getCount()`.

Additionally, you should combine your methods so that you don't make redundant queries to the database:

```
public String[] getValues(long l) {
    String[] results = new String[2]; 
    String[] columns = new String[]{ EMP_DEPT, EMP_DATE1 };
    Cursor c = db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        results[0] = c.getString(0);
        results[1] = c.getString(1);
    } else {
        Log.d("GET_VALUES", "No results formed from this query!");
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this matter.    I will definitely have to combine the methods.    I got it working with a simple try catch statment but your aproch seems better.   Will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a single query to get all values at once:

```
SELECT Date1 FROM MyTable WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 12345
```

or:

```java
db.query(EMP_TABLE, columns, EMP_ID + " BETWEEN 1 AND " + ..., ...);
```

Then missing values will just not show up when you iterate over the cursor.